# Is there no way to do this purely via CSS?

Tags: javascript, html, css, forms, checkbox

I've got this CSS rule...

```
input[checked="false"] + label {opacity: .6}
```

For this HTML...

```
<input type="checkbox" checked="true" name="whatever" value="whatever" id="whatever">
<label for="whatever">Whatever</label>
```

And I would think that as I check or uncheck them, it would become opaque or semi-transparent. **However**, it turns out the `checked="true` attribute doesn't change when the DOM `element.checked` does, since the former is simply the *default value*.

As such, I've bootstrapped it with a bit of JavaScript...

```
document.getElementById('whatever').addEventListener('change', toggleChecked, false);
function toggleChecked() {
    this.setAttribute('checked', this.checked);
}
```

Basically, my question is whether this is necessary or not. Is there some way to change the label's style via CSS only, based on the checked-or-not status of its checkbox?

Comment: `false` is not a valid value of `checked`. It's either `checked` in HTML or `checked="checked"` in XHTML, or nothing if unchecked. `true` and `false` in the DOM are Boolean values.

Comment: You've got a point, but even if I simply used `checked`, unchecking the box doesn't remove the HTML attribute, so the problem still stands. Er, stood, since idealmachine mentioned the `:checked` pseudo-class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There exists the [`:checked` CSS3 pseudo class](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#checked), but it does not work on Internet Explorer (at least version 8 and below).

```
input:checked + label {opacity: .6}
```